# access vba: referencing other accdb's & late binding

Tags: ms-access, vba, late-binding

I'm working in Access 2013 VBA, trying to collect back-end functions & user-defined types in a separate package, separated the code into 2 .accdb files with a reference from the front-end to back-end.

This seems to work, but user-defined types in the back-end are not visible from the front-end, forcing all front-end instances of back-end types be declared as objects & public functions returning the user-defined types be defined in the back-end.

This late-binding approach gives 1) no intellisense & 2) much less readable code.

When i reference ADODB, for example, I can use types such as `ADODB.RecordSet` (with intellisense). How to get this behavior from references to other .accdb's?

Comment: How are your two databases related? Did you set a reference to the back-end from the front end?